# Adding scrolling programmatically when needed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a screen set up in my app with all the constraints and everything, and so don't want to set up a scroll view for this view in the interface builder if it means that I will lose the constraints.

The content size varies, so I only want to make the view scrollable if it goes off the screen.

Is there a way to make this view scrollable without the constraints being deleted? (If it can be done in the interface builder without changing constraints, then please say)

Answer (score 0):

1- Drag a scrollView behind it and hook it's leading , trailing , top and bottom to superView

2- Copy that view you want to make it scroll-bale , paste it inside the scrollview with L,T,T,B constraints to the scrollView and Equal width to top outer view

BTW: You can also use embed from

> Editor -> EmbedIn -> scrollView

**Note:** this won't break inner constraints of the view , but you will lose only the constraints of the view itself